# Windows scheduled task to git push to github

Tags: windows, git, github, msysgit

I hope to add a Windows Scheduled Task to git push to github every night.  I have a CMD file.  When I run the CMD file on the windows command prompt, it works fine.  But when I run it via windows scheduled task.  It's stuck forever.  The status is "running".  And from the log I can see it successfully started the git bash shell.  Any idea?

```
echo git push > i:\gitpush
echo 'pushing' >>log1
C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cmd.exe  /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login i:\gitpush" >>log1 2>>error    
echo 'done pushing' >>log1
del i:\gitpush
```

Here is the log output:

```
'pushing'
Welcome to Git (version 1.7.4-preview20110204)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.
```

Then I did an experiment to rename gitpush script to a wrong file name.  And it exited immediately with the error "No such file or directory", which is expected.  It shows the gitpush script is passing in correctly to the bash but for some reason it's stuck.

The reason I have to go through git bash shell is because I don't know how to setup public key in windows command line shell without using git bash shell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know how to setup public key in windows command line shell

Public/private keys work also in a DOS shell, provided you define the `%HOME%` environment variable (referencing the parent directory of the `.ssh`)

The trick with Windows Scheduled Task is to make sure:

- *who* is actually running the task (the "system account"? or the actual user?)
  Displaying "`env`" can help debugging the issue.
- *where* it is run: if git push depends on the current path to properly push the current repo, you need to be certain that your task runs where it is supposed to.

Comment: My case was invoking a scheduled powershell script which worked when logged in but ssh.exe hung when run as a task. Explicitly setting $env:HOME = "path-to-home" before calling into git fixed it.

Comment: What's the trick to getting it to run out of the current repo? Is it just a matter of putting the file within that repo??? I'm currently calling a file in, for example, C:/a when the git repo path is actually C:/b

Comment: @exhoosier10 you could consider setting the environment variable `GIT_DIR` to `C:\b` (or calling git with `git --git-dir=C:\b your git command`)